# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blog'

Tags: python, django

Made a new app called Blog and now not able to import it. 
created basic apps called products, pages. Now adding one more app called Blog into the project. Not able to solve migrate issues and terminal ends up with no model named 'Blog' import error:

Here is my directory structure:

```
> Dev
    > python3
    > trydjango
        > src
            > blog
                > migrations
                > templates
                HTML FILES
                PYTHON FILE
            > pages
            > products
                > migrations
                > templates
            > templates
            > trydjango
            SETTINGS,URL,WSGI
```

here is BLOG/models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Article(models.Model):
    title       =   models.CharField(max_length=120)
    abstract    =   models.CharField()
    author      =   models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on  =   models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

here is Blog/view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    DetailView,
    ListView,
    UpdateView,
    ListView,
    DeleteView
)

from .models import Article
# Create your views here.


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

TRACEBACK:

`````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blog'
(trydjango) Kuldeeps-MacBook-Pro:src kuldeep$ 


````
`````

Comment: `blog` != `Blog` != `BLOG`

Comment: If you have a traceback you need to include it in your question. Also, you don't have a Blog model (you have an Article model in your blog/models.py file).

Comment: ````
$ python manage.py makemigations
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in 
  execute_from_command_line
      utility.execute()
    File "/Users/kuldeep/Dev/trydjango/lib/python3.7/site- 
 packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
      django.setup()
.
.
.

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blog'
```

Comment: @thebjorn, does not change even if I try to change model name Blog or Article !

Comment: 1. you should `import .blog` 2. do you have `__init__.py` under `./blog` directory?

Comment: And you are using `blog` and `Blog` and `BLOG` in 3 different places. Have you read the first comment? Which one is **actually** you are using?

Comment: Hi, the problem is resolved with 3 diferent Blog typo. Thanks @Daniel, 
  @knh190. But still confused with following two questions:
````
  1. Creation of Blog App. ??
  
  2. Creation of Model called Article. ??

What is app and what is model ? 
`````

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Very frustrating, especially coming from python2.

You have to add a `.` to the module, regardless of whether or not it is relative or absolute.

Comment: where to put . ?

Answer (score 0):

As the Daniel suggested problem is being resolved and no more error of import. Thanks. Now it extended me in bizarre situation because I want to create following two tasks:

1. Creation of BLOG App.
2. Creation of model called Article in BLOG App.

Any good explanation for that please?

Answer (score 0):

I want to contribute here because on my case, the mistake was a tiny one, but really confronting. Look, when you add the name of your app to settings.py, you need not to forget a comma after the app name.

This is the comma you need not to forget: (in red)

[image]